# How to get the current context inside a class in android?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have the following android code snippet

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void makeQuery(String symbol) {   
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Alarm.this);
        ....
```

and I am trying to call `makeQuery` from my main activity. However, during compilation, I get the following error:

```
actual argument Alarm cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion
```

I understand that the current object cannot be converted into a `context`, which `Volley` obviously needs. Is this a property of `BroadcastReceiver`?  Can the `this`-variable only be converted into a `context` for special classes? Should I move this function `makeQuery` into a different class?

I am preliminary interested in an explanation rather than a solution!

In Addition: The current setup is for testing purposes only. The method later is called from within the `Alarm` class itself! Then there is no Main Activity! I need a solution to make it work then!

`MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
        alarm.makeQuery("Test");
```

Comment: Post the code where you actually call the `makeQuery` method from **MainActivity**.

Comment: I have updated this in the question

Answer (score 4):

Use the **application**'s context to avoid leaking the Activity or the broadcast receiver if someone passes one in:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private Context mContext;

    public Alarm() {}

    public Alarm(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void makeQuery(String symbol) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext.getApplicationContext());
    }

    ....
}
```

The `RequestQueue` expects an **Activity** or an **Application** context:

**MainActivity.java**

```
Alarm alarm = new Alarm(this); // Pass in the Activity's context
alarm.makeQuery("Test");
```

Comment: Calling the method from the main activity is just for testing purposes. I plan to call this method later from the Alarm class itself! Then I have no context and your suggestion does not work!

Comment: Well, this class will be instantiated, sooner or later right ?

Comment: But now I get an error during running: "Alarm has no zero argument constructor" upon trying

Comment: add the no-args constructor : `public Alarm() {}`

Comment: yes, sure! After reading the error again, I also came up with this. I just hope, the class is never instantiated and used without argument, as the context will be null...

Comment: I believe that you will never have to use the **no-args** constructor, since you control the instantiation of the object, you can always choose the **overloaded** one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95835/discussion-between-alex-and-jdev).

Answer (score 1):

`BroadcastReceiver` **not inherits** from `Context`, so you can't use your `Alarm` class as context.

You can use the activity Context:

```
public void makeQuery(Context context, String symbol) {   
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        ....
}
```

And from activity:

```
Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
alarm.makeQuery(MainActivity.this, "Test");
```

Comment: But WHY is that? I am more interested in the WHY? Does a BroadcastReceiver not have a context?

Comment: Activity inherits Context while BroadcastReceiver not, so you can cast an Activity to Context and not a BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Alarm.this);
```

`Alarm` extending `BroadcastReceiver` but `BroadcastReceiver` is not sub-class of `Context` class. so it's not possible to use the class's context which is not extending Service,Activity,FragmentActivity,... as Context.

In `BroadcastReceiver` `onReceive` method contains two parameters first parameter is Context which you can also use as a Context for creating Volley requests. like:

Comment: Finally an explanation which makes sense! Thanks

Comment: @Alex: my question is why extending `BroadcastReceiver ` in Alarm class?

Comment: I followed an example given here (the idea later is that this method is being called from with this Alarm class, set up by a service):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example